# Как получить значение выбранного элемента в ListBox, используя WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Как получить элемент, который выбран в ListBox?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ListBox Name="release_date" Margin="475,135,192,329">
        <ListBoxItem Background="LightGray">2021</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Background="LightGray">2020</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Background="LightGray">2019</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Background="LightGray">2018</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Background="LightGray">2017</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
uint RELEASE_DATE = ... //хотелось бы видеть здесь число 2019
```

---

**Как он выглядит:**

[image: мой listbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public ObservableCollection<uint> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<uint>()
{
    2021,
    2020,
    2019,
    2018,
    2017
};

public uint ReleaseDate { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding ReleaseDate}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
       </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Всё, теперь `ReleaseDate` - нужное свойство. А элементы в `ListBox` вы можете добавлять и удалять в реальном времени не изменяя код приложения, просто меняя элементы в коллекции `Items`.